# Filter JavaRDD based on a ArrayList of index id's

Tags: apache-spark, java-8, apache-spark-dataset

I have Dataset df with contents which have an index as accountid and I also have array list with accountids. How do I filter or map the Dataset to create a new Dataset that has only contents based on the accountid in the arraylist.

I am using Java 8

```
List<String> accountIdList= new ArrayList<String>();
accountIdList.add("1001");
accountIdList.add("1002");
accountIdList.add("1003");
accountIdList.add("1004");
Dataset<Row> filteredRows=  df.filter(p-> df.col("accountId").equals(accountIdList));
```

I am trying to pass the list itself for the comparison operator do you think this is the correct approach

The Java syntax is

If you are looking for the java syntax

```
Dataset<Row> filteredRows=  df.where(df.col("accountId").isin(accountIdList.toArray()));
```

Comment: If you are looking for the java syntax  Dataset<Row> filteredRows=  df.where(df.col("accountId").isin(accountIdList.toArray()));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Column.isin` method:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

Dataset<Row> filteredRows = df.where(col("accountId").isin(
  JavaConversions.asScalaIterator(accountIdList.iterator()).toSeq()
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code in Java. Hope it helps .

This is my sampleFile Content (input):-

1001

1008

1005

1009

1010

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FilterFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class DatasetFilter {

    private static List<String> sampleList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        sampleList.add("1001");
        sampleList.add("1002");
        sampleList.add("1003");
        sampleList.add("1004");
        sampleList.add("1005");

        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
                .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/Users/user/workspace/Validation/spark-warehouse")
                .master("local[*]").getOrCreate();

        //Read the source-file.
        Dataset<String> src = sparkSession.read().textFile("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\dataSetFilterTest.txt");
        src.show(10);

        //Apply filter
        Dataset<String> filteredSource = src.filter(new FilterFunction<String>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public boolean call(String value) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("***************************************");
                boolean status = false;
                Iterator<String> iterator = sampleList.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    String val = iterator.next();
                    System.out.println("Val is :: " + val + " Value is :: " + value);
                    if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(val)) {
                        status = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return status;
            }
        });

        filteredSource.show();

        System.out.println("Completed the job :)");
    }

}
```

Output:-

[image]